# Highcharts scatter plot with lots of data points running really slow

Tags: highcharts

I've seen a few suggestions here, but nothing seems to apply to my situation.  I've also seen some unresolved similar issues.  I have scatter plot with a lot of data (about 40k) points.  It's really slow.  The link below (genetic data - called a Manhattan plot) will eventually load, but it's just slow. I need to find a way to optimize performance.

http://ricediversity.org/test/highcharts/examples/line-ajax/index-b.htm

Also, I'm trying to add additional info (data fields) to my tooltip from my data file, but I can't get that working either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Highcharts draws plots using SVG.  Each `piece` of the plot is written into the DOM within the SVG container tag.  You've just created 40K point objects.

Comment: Please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there . Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: You should look into highstock and the `datagrouping` option:  http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Comment: I thought about datagrouping and highstock.  But I read on one of these forums that it'll only work using dates and times.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to disable animations / shadows.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.animation
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.animation
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.shadow

Answer (score 1):

As far as tooltips, check out the [highcharts data api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data), specifically number 2 in the list. If that doesn't cut it for you, you can pass in an array of objects where you specify the data you want to get. Then, in the formatter, it is easy to reference. [Here's a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/38/) showing how to reference the names once they're in your data array.

The formatter is

```
formatter: function () {
    var s = "";
    $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
        s += point.point.nameList[0];
    });
    return s;
}
```

and the data sets look like:

```
data = [ ..., 
         {x: xval, y: yval, nameList: myListOfNames},
         ...]
```

where `xval` and `yval` are the x and y values of the data points and `myListOfNames` is an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are some hints on optimising performance on the highcharts website here: http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$optimize-performance

However, with that many points, I would consider using highstock. There is no way to make out the detail of that many points, so aggregating them in some way would make a better chart (http://docs.highcharts.com/#data-grouping).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too late to be useful (and the example link no longer works, so I'm not sure if this applies), but there's a newish Highcharts plugin to downsample time series data with the intent to retain the shape of the original data.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/13/Highcharts-Downsample