# Is it possible to plot more than 35000 points in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Im trying to plot that quantity of points but after more or less 960 points it does not work anymore. Any idea of this is possible? or its a problem of my code?

Comment: It should work, but be increasingly slow. Highstock has grouping, which helps deal with this.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750515/highcharts-scatter-plot-with-lots-of-data-points-running-really-slow

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) parameter as 0

```
plotOptions:{
      series:{
           turboThreshold: 0
      }
}
```